# PowerShell move window between desktops

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, winapi

I wannt to move a window between desktops.
Something like this:

```
$app  = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru
sleep 1
$hndl = $app.MainWindowHandle

# Move notepad window to desktop №2
[DesktopManager]::MoveToDesktop($hndl, 2) # True

# Get the number of desktop, where the app is located now
[DesktopManager]::GetDesktopWindow($hndl) # 2

#etc...
```

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983767/how-to-move-a-window-between-desktops-using-powershell-net-on-windows-10) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416843/altering-win10-virtual-desktop-behavior/32417530#32417530), but I don't understand how to run it via PowerShell.

Also i have found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager?redirectedfrom=MSDN)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the thing you ask about was intentionally not allowed by Windows APIs. I see that the pages you linked to use the IVirtualDesktopManager interface but it is not intended to move foreign windows.

Raymond Chen's article [Virtual desktops are an end-user window management feature, not a programmatic one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201123-00/?p=104476) about the IVirtualDesktopManager interface says "the only thing you can do is make one window join another window’s virtual desktop... [the interface] is not a general purpose interface for moving windows onto arbitrary virtual desktops."

Also, [here](https://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/105416/blog3671.html) (the post is in Russian; the translation is mine) it is said that: "MoveWindowToDesktop works only for windows launched by the process, i.e. it is not possible to move a foreign window with this function."